# Inherit only a Subset of Fields of Pydantic Model

Tags: python, inheritance, pydantic

I would like to generate a Pydantic model that inherits from a parent class, but only has a subset of that parent model's fields.

E.g. `ModelB` should inherit only `field_b` from `ModelA`:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class ModelA(BaseModel):
    field_a: str
    field_b: str

class ModelB(ModelA):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was enough for me to hard copy the field and to adjust the extras I had defined. Here is a snippet from my code:

```
import copy

from pydantic import BaseModel


def copy_primary_field(
        model_from: BaseModel,
        model_to: BaseModel,
        primary_key: str,
) -> BaseModel:
    new_field_name = f"{model_from.__name__}" + "_" + primary_key
    model_to.__fields__[new_field_name] = copy.deepcopy(
        model_from.__fields__[primary_key]
    )
    model_to.__fields__[new_field_name].name = new_field_name
    model_to.__fields__[new_field_name].field_info.extra["references"] = (
            f"{model_from.__name__}" + ":" + primary_key
    )

    return model_to
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no built-in mechanism for this in Pydantic.

### Difficult solutions

You *could* start messing around with the internals like `__fields__`
and `__fields_set__`, but I would strongly advise against it. I think this may be less than trivial because you need to take into account validators that are already registered and maybe a bunch of other stuff that happens internally, one a field is defined on a model.

You *could* also go the route of e.g. defining your own `__init_subclass__` on `ModelA` or even subclassing `ModelMetaclass`, but this will likely lead to the same difficulties. Unless you are *very* familiar with the intricacies of Pydantic models *and* are prepared to rework your code, if something fundamentally changes on their end, I would not recommend this.

I can think of a few workarounds though.

---

### Potential workarounds

The simplest one in my opinion is simply factoring out the fields that you want to share into their own model:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class ModelWithB(BaseModel):
    field_b: str


class ModelA(ModelWithB):
    field_a: str


class ModelB(ModelWithB):
    pass
```

This obviously doesn't work, if you have no control over `ModelA`. It also may mess up the order of the fields on `ModelA` (in this case `field_b` would come before `field_a`), which may or may not be important to you. Validation for example depends on the order in which fields were defined.

Another possible workaround would be to override the unneeded field in `ModelB` and make it optional with a `None` default and exclude it from `dict` and `json` exports:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class ModelA(BaseModel):
    field_a: str
    field_b: str


class ModelB(ModelA):
    field_a: str | None = Field(default=None, exclude=True)


b = ModelB(field_b="foo")
print(b.json())
```

Output:

```
{"field_b": "foo"}
```

Note that this does **not** actually get rid of the field. It is still there and by default still visible in the model's string representation for example, as well as in the model schema. But at least you never need to pass a value for `field_a` and it is not present, when calling `dict` or `json` by  default.

Note also that you may run into addtional problems, if you have custom validators for `field_a` that don't work with a `None` value.

---

If you provide more details, I might amend this answer, but so far I hope this helps a little.

Comment: THX. However in the end I need an automatic approach without providing any structure of ModelB. Now, I do try your first not recommended idea: Messing around with __fields__

Comment: @LazlooXp One problem you will probably run into, if you try to add that kind of functionality on top of the regular model class, is that the type hinting provided by plugins for Pydantic will certainly break. Nothing you can do (aside from writing your won type checker plugin) can change that. The `__init__` method hints will stay the same, even if you succeed in implementing that functionality. I would still advise not doing this, and instead posting this as a feature request in their issue tracker. If you succeed, I would still be interested in the solution.